# Conda not using latest package version

Tags: scipy, package, anaconda, conda

I am using Anaconda (latest version of september). I have executed 'conda update --all' to get the latest packages, in particular Scipy. But when I import scipy from a python shell, it's only importing the 1.7.3 version, not the latest one (1.9.1).

I am not fluent with the conda framework. I tried running `conda install scipy` which did not change anything, and `conda install scipy=1.9.1` (which seems to hang).

I am using the base environment. This is a fresh isntall of the latest Anconda (with package update via conda, not any use of pip that could interfere).

Listing the packages via conda yields:

```bash
>>> conda list scipy
# packages in environment at /home/***/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
scipy                     1.7.3            py39hc147768_0
```

However, when I look at the content of the `anaconda3/pkgs` folder:

```bash
>>> ls anaconda3/pkgs/ | grep scipy

anaconda3/pkgs/scipy-1.7.3-py39hc147768_0.conda
anaconda3/pkgs/scipy-1.9.1-py39h14f4228_0.conda
anaconda3/pkgs/scipy-1.7.3-py39hc147768_0 (contains Scipy 1.7.3)
anaconda3/pkgs/scipy-1.9.1-py39h14f4228_0 (contains Scipy 1.9.1)
anaconda3/pkgs/scipy-1.9.1-py39h14f4228_09jfxaf1g (empty folder)
anaconda3/pkgs/scipy-1.9.1-py39h14f4228_0dydy5wnw (empty folder)
```

So I am assuming that conda has both Scipy 1.7.3 and 1.9.1. But why can't I import the lastest one ?

How may I correct this situation ?

EDIT: creating a new environment and reinstalling the packages as needed solves my problem. However, how come the base environment is stuck with the earlier version ?

Comment: Anaconda has hundreds of packages each with their own version constraints. Sometimes one package's constraints conflict with another's, preventing the latest versions of everything from being coinstalled.

Comment: Try the `mamba` package manager (https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba). It's a drop-in replacement for `conda` but uses a different dependency resolution algorithm.